# Function to store modal object to database dynamically using PDO that accespts serialized objects as values

Tags: php, mysql, serialization, pdo

I am writing an app that uses PDO. I have a model abstract class that defines a property of id. I create a class that extends the abstract for each object model with propertis and methods unique to each data modal, and use PDO fetchObject to get objects from the database. if id is NULL, I know it hasn't been saved. I have a function that worked until I tried passing a serialized object as a property. The problem occurs when a property of the serialized object contains a single quote. (ex. Mike's Hard Lemonade) Here is the function that resides in the modal abstract class:

```
public function save(DatabaseConnection &$db)
{
    $properties = get_object_vars($this);
    $table = $this->getTableName();
    foreach ($properties as $key => $value) {
        $cols[] = "`$key`";
        $values[] = "'".$value."'";
        if ($value != NULL) {
            $updateCols[] = "`$key`".' = "'.$value.'"';
        }
    }

    $sql = 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' ('.implode(", ", $cols).') VALUES ('.implode(", ", $values).') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE '.implode(", ", $updateCols);
    var_dump($sql);
    $stmnt = $db->prepare($sql);
    return $stmnt->execute($values);
}
```

Comment: Lovely [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability...

Comment: And if you'd bother to follow the link and read what it has to say, you'd get the answer to your problem. "... contains a single quote ...". e.g. you're performing an injection attack on yourself.

Comment: You are just using PDO wrong way

Comment: @MarcB I have read that article. Not worried about sql injection as that is handled in my controller. Just looking for a way to change this to implement bindParam(), which would eliminate any threat of injection anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($properties as $key => $value) {
    $value = $db->quote($value);
```

Still not a good idea to store objects this way.  Especially if the objects themselves map to a database.  But it will get rid of your embedded quote problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got it! This site was great when I first joined. Today it seems that there is nothing but negative people wanting only to find flaws instead of answer questions, or flame those who do offer possible solutions. I don't think that is what this site is about. Thanks Cerad for offering a possible solution. Your effort is appreciated.

```
public function save(DatabaseConnection &$db)
{
    $properties = get_object_vars($this);
    $table = $this->getTableName();
    $values = array_filter($properties, 'strlen');

    if (array_key_exists('id', $values)) {
        unset($values['id']);
        foreach (array_keys($values) as $col_name) if ($col_name !== 'id') $a[] = "$col_name = ?";
        $valuesString = implode(', ', $a);
        $stmnt = $db->prepare("UPDATE $table SET {$valuesString} WHERE id = {$this->id}");
    } else {
        $columnString = implode(',', array_keys($values));
        $valueString = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($values), '?'));
        $stmnt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO $table ({$columnString}) VALUES ({$valueString})");
    }
    return $stmnt->execute(array_values($values));
}
```